# How can I add two rows in a single pdf cell?

Tags: c#, itext

I am generatng barcode. Now I want to insert the student code under the barcode label. How can I do this?My code is

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdBarcode.Rows)
{
  DataList dl = (DataList)row.FindControl("datalistBarcode");
  PdfContentByte cb = new PdfContentByte(writer);
  PdfPTable BarCodeTable = new PdfPTable(6);
  BarCodeTable.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 100,10,100,10,100,10 });
  BarCodeTable.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
  Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
  code128.CodeType = Barcode.CODE128_UCC;
   foreach (DataListItem dli in dl.Items)
     {
        String barcodename= ((Label)dli.FindControl("lblBarCode")).Text;
        string studentcode= ((Label)dli.FindControl("lblStudCode")).Text;
        code128.Code = "*" + productID1 + "*";

        iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
        BarCodeTable.AddCell(image128);
        BarCodeTable.AddCell("");           
    }
 doc.Add(BarCodeTable);
```

My present Output is
[image]

I want to bring the Student code also under the barcode label. Please show me a way to achieve it

Or let me know how to pass more than one parameters throgh pdftable.Addcell() function..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the `Image` object directly to a `PdfPCell` like this:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
BarCodeTable.AddCell(image128);
```

The second line is a short cut for something that looks like this:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.SetImage(image128);
BarCodeTable.AddCEll(cell);
```

This `cell` contains nothing more than an image. There is no room for text.

If you want to combine an image and text, you need something like this:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(image128);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Student name");
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell.AddElement(p);
BarCodeTable.AddCEll(cell);
```

Comment: Once again you saved me..Thaaankz a looooot dear :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var p = new Paragraph();
p.Add("First line text\n");
p.Add("    Second line text\n");
p.Add("    Third line text\n");
p.Add("Fourth line text\n");
myTable.AddCell(p);
```

You could also get complicated and use a sub-table if you need more control:

```
var subTable = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10, 100 });                        
subTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("First line text")) { Colspan = 2, Border = 0 });
subTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { Border = 0 });
subTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Second line text")) {  Border = 0 });
subTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { Border = 0 });
subTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Third line text")) { Border = 0 });
subTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Fourth line text")) { Colspan = 2, Border = 0 });
myTable.AddCell(subTable);
```

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/86/itextsharp-introducing-tables